# How do I fix the error "cannot find the module package.json"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have started learning angular 2 a couple of days ago and everything was going fine until yesterday. My app was running fine when I left the work and slept. And when I tried to continue the work today, I started getting this error. In the beginning there was a typescript error which I fixed by installing typescript locally. After I fixed that, the app started throwing this error with the package.json module every time I ran `npm start`. Can anyone help me fix it?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Comment: concurrently module corrupted. Removed it in package.json will solve your problem. Can you show package.json?

Comment: I removed concurrently module from the package.json but the error persists. And, how do you want me to show you the package.json??

Comment: Run npm install again.

Comment: I did. but it is still there

Answer (score 3):

Just experienced this same issue with a yarn + vue.js project and have been scratching my head at what could be causing this. Eventually solved it by executing `rm -R` on the `node_modules` directory then then reinstalling everything with `yarn install` (or npm install). After that the local server started as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in the console error message, try getting the newest version of npm. If you have the newest version, then try making sure nothing is wrong with the Angular Quickstart package itself. I'm not sure if this will help, but good luck!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with the Angular quickstart package because everything was working fine yesterday. But today when I started to run `npm start`, it threw that error

Comment: Okay, can you show where the file is located (go into finder and show it)

Comment: you mean the package.json file?

Comment: Yeah, but do you have a mac?

Comment: by the way, how do you want me to show you where that file is?